# How can an email reply or forward be composed in html emails?

Tags: html-email, composition, reply

I'm creating a simple email client and I'm having trouble with Reply and Forward in html emails.

When I have the user compose the reply message, how do I append that content to the top of the message? I have done some investigating with how outlook does it by injecting the new message content into a paragraph or div or something like that.

How is it done in general, i.e. gmail, yahoo, etc. How do they figure out where to inject the reply content in the html?

I'm using c# so ideally there is some c# library that can handle this? If not then some idea how it's done generally so I can create a solution for it.

I've read wikipedia's [Posting Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posting_style) article and it gives a good overview of the general idea but nothing about how to do it in html.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Can the downvoter please comment to help me make this a useful question for others? I haven't seen any questions like this on SO.

Comment: @EricJ. I am not having any problem composing emails from scratch and sending them. System.Net.Mail is in fact what I'm using. But it has nothing about how to handle replies and forwards.

Comment: You handle a reply or forward just as you would compose a new email, except that you will set the appropriate from/to headers, possibly change the subject line (commonly by prepending Re: or Fwd:), and copy as much as seems appropriate to MailMessage.Body.  Beyond that, I don't understand what you are struggling with.  BTW I'm not the downvoter so cannot comment on that.

Comment: @EricJ. Yes but the message body is a valid html document with html tags, body tag etc. You can't just append the new content at the top (for example above the html tag) or just anywhere. There must be a specific way to do it. Possibly you just inject the new content directly after the <body> tag, but some of the outlook emails have lots of gobblety-gook between the body tag and the actual start of content, so I don't want to assume.

Comment: I see what your question is now.  I'll try to answer it.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'm eagerly awaiting your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some Background**

When composing HTML email, it is important to recognize that email clients have rather limited support for HTML and the level of support varies across email clients.

Because of that, although `<div>` and CSS are the correct layout tools for web pages, that is not true for HTML email.  Even today, use `<table>` for layout control for HTML emails.

Additionally, the only reliable means to apply CSS is to the HTML elements with a `style=` attribute on each element.  CSS declarations in a `<head>` section are often ignored by the email client.  When crafting HTML email, I actually use CSS in the `<head>` and, once it looks correct, use [this page](https://putsmail.com/inliner#inliner_result_container) to convert the HTML to use `style=` attributes.  There are [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code).

Not only will the `<head>` tag often be ignored, but so will any `<body>` tag.

**Solving Your Problem**

I would suggest placing the text included in the reply within a table (with a single `<tr>` and single `<td>`), and applying an inline CSS style to that table.  That allows you to apply formatting, such as placing a colored bar down the left-hand side, italicizing the text, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Eric. And should I just grab everything in the body tag and consider that the original message, put that into a row, and then insert my new content into a row above it?